# How to check whether Clickhouse server-settings is really applied?

Tags: clickhouse

I applied the setting `max_concurrent_queries` for CH, but not sure whether it is taking effect or not.

Can this setting value be queried from the clickhouse-client? I couldn't find any command to do that. Could someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*max_concurrent_queries* is [server param](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/) that configured through config-file:

For example:

```sh
sudo nano /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/config.xml
```

config.xml:

```xml
<yandex>
     <max_concurrent_queries>256</max_concurrent_queries>
</yandex>
```

Check that is was assigned to config:

```sh
sudo cat /var/lib/clickhouse/preprocessed_configs/config.xml
```

Restart service to apply it:

```sh
sudo service clickhouse-server restart
```