# Check if a setting was applied with clickhouse-client

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

How can I check if a cluster setting is applied on server?

For example,
I run `--query "SET allow_experimental_live_view = 1"` on my cluster.
Which query should I use to check that this setting was changed? Is it possible to do with **clickhouse-client** command?

This question is similar but does not answer mine [How to check whether Clickhouse server-settings is really applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65950979/how-to-check-whether-clickhouse-server-settings-is-really-applied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*clickhouse-client* has many options. Let's check them:

```sh
clickhouse-client --help

...
  --allow_experimental_live_view arg                               Enable LIVE VIEW. Not mature enough.
  --live_view_heartbeat_interval arg                               The heartbeat interval in seconds to indicate live query is alive.
  --max_live_view_insert_blocks_before_refresh arg                 Limit maximum number of inserted blocks after which mergeable blocks are dropped and query is re-executed.
...
```

It needs to pass it this way:

```sh
clickhouse-client --allow_experimental_live_view 1
```

To check the current settings use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM system.settings
WHERE name LIKE '%_live_%'

┌─name───────────────────────────────────────┬─value─┬─changed─┬─description────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─min──┬─max──┬─readonly─┬─type────┐
│ tcp_keep_alive_timeout                     │ 0     │       0 │ The time in seconds the connection needs to remain idle before TCP starts sending keepalive probes         │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │        0 │ Seconds │
│ allow_experimental_live_view               │ 1     │       1 │ Enable LIVE VIEW. Not mature enough.                                                                       │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │        0 │ Bool    │
│ max_live_view_insert_blocks_before_refresh │ 64    │       0 │ Limit maximum number of inserted blocks after which mergeable blocks are dropped and query is re-executed. │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │        0 │ UInt64  │
│ temporary_live_view_timeout                │ 5     │       0 │ Timeout after which temporary live view is deleted.                                                        │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │        0 │ Seconds │
│ periodic_live_view_refresh                 │ 60    │       0 │ Interval after which periodically refreshed live view is forced to refresh.                                │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │        0 │ Seconds │
└────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────┴─────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────────┴─────────┘
```

To run this query around all cluster nodes see [is there a better way to query system tables across a clickhouse cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67340942/303298).

Comment: Hi @vladimir, if we do this clickhouse-client --allow_experimental_live_view 1 , does it apply to the current session or to the entire ch cluster?

Comment: Hi @sylvinho81, it be applied to the current session. To apply it persistently follow this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/65951690/303298 .

Comment: So @vladimir, "clickhouse-client --allow_experimental_live_view 1" has the same effect than "SET allow_experimental_live_view = 1". So if I create a Live View within a specific session it not going to be available if other user opens an another session. is that what you mean?

Comment: @sylvinho81
You understood it right.